# How to mass-assign in rails even though attributes are in attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my like.rb I have:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :liked, :product_id, :user_id
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
@like = Product.new(:product_id => params[:id].to_i, :user_id => current_user.id, :liked => "Yes")
@like.save
```

However I get an error saying Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product_id, user_id, liked.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: use the setters directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have set the attributes as accessible on the `Like` model, but you're trying to mass-assign on the `Product` model. If you set `attr_accessible` there, you should find things work better.

Answer (score 1):

@Chowlett's answer is correct. If you have fixed set of attributes to assign (like in your example), you can use `without_protection` flag:

```
@like = Product.new({product_id: params[:id].to_i, user_id: current_user.id, liked: 'Yes'}, without_protection: true)
```